# How to handle non objects in VueJS loop in laravel 5.4?

Tags: arrays, laravel, vue.js

How can I display an array with objects in laravel 5.4. without getting errors if an object is `null`.

Data: [array list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mugC7.png)

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
echo $post->user->name; // display successfuly name of user
echo $post->likes->id; // show error - Trying to get property of non-object  }
```

Comment: Please show the in -and output you require and show us what you have already tried

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow. [...] Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Jerodev

'
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->user->name; // display successfuly name of user
    echo $post->likes->id; // show error - Trying to get property of non-object
  }
'

Comment: That's because `$post->likes` is `null` for the first object

Comment: @Jerodev so what is the solution for this
every post have not likes.
how should i  modify my function ?

Comment: @hardeepcoder Please don't post code as images.

Comment: @hardeepcoder Also this is not a multidimensional array.

Comment: @RolandStuder sorry and thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not every `$post` has a like, so you are basically trying to access a property of `null` which is, obviously, not an object. Your way around this is simple and I think you are overlooking it because you are expecting Laravel to just handle that error for you.

```
@foreach( $posts as $post )
  <p>{{ $post->name }}</p>
  <p>{{ $post->likes ? $post->likes->id : 'No Likes' }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Also, keep in mind here you have called it `likes`, which leads me believe it a one to many relationship (a post can have MANY likes). In that case, you are going to need to loop over `$posts->likes` to get the ID for each one:

```
@foreach($posts as $post )
  <p>{{ $post->name }}</p>
  <p>
    @if( $post->likes)
      @foreach( $post->likes as $like )
        {{ $like->id }} @if (!$loop->last), @endif
      @endforeach
    @else
      'No Likes';
    @endif
  </p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: you are right now friend, but you know i want to compare my logged user id if this user liked this particular post or not like
`<p v-if="like.user_id=='{{Auth::user()->id}}'"> liked by you</p>
`
but then its showing multiple time because its inside the likes loop